# trying to make a wavy edge

Tags: objects, edit-mode

I'm a beginner in blender and was looking around for learning the basics. I found some videos on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5Gb1VK98Wc) (the last 10 minutes have what I'm trying to do) and at the end of one a donut is made but the icing is supposed to be wavy on the edge. so when I select the bottom layers and put the setting on random and pull down there are no waves being made. rather the entier layer is stretched down and the top half gets wavy. then when I hide the top half and only use the bottom row of vertices they still just get stretched downwards. any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what happens is not very clear, you should put some screenshots. Perhaps the problem is the influence radius of the Proportional Editing mode, i.e. the circle that appears when you enable the Proportional Editing, either clicking on the circle button on the horizontal menu bar on the bottom of the 3D view, or pressing O or alt O. Sometimes the influence radius is too large so you can't even see it. Anyway maybe the problem is that radius. Check out a tutorial about Proportional Editing.

Comment: Hello!  When asking questions, it is best to inline your concerns as pictures and well worded questions. Referring to a long youtube video will not get you much engagement, or good answers.  

Can you please edit your question with pictures of what you are trying to do along with what is happening instead?

Answer (score -2):

Two possible scenarios:

Did you select every single vertices on the bottom ring? If so, stop. Just select one vertex when using the proportional editing tool for this. Use the scroll wheel to increase the fall off of the proportional editing tool.

Do you have the subsurface modifier enabled? If not, the random function will make it jagged.